# Accessing executing folder when running a jar file

Tags: java

I would like to be able to run a jar file `java -jar myapp.jar` on different folders and have it load `config.properties` based on the executing context.

```
/myapp/myapp.jar

/folder1/config.properties
/folder2/java -jar /myapp/myapp.jar    <------ loads /folder1/config.properties

/some/folder2/config.properties
/some/folder2/java -jar /myapp/myapp.jar   <------ loads /folder2/config.properties
```

Once the properties are loaded, I want it to then create some files in the current execution folder.

So:

1. How do I tell java to load a properties file based on the current executing context?
2. How do I get access the folder that the jar was executing from?

Comment: `new File("config.properties")`

Comment: So that wont load from `/myapp/config.properties`?

Comment: No. Relative file paths are resolved relative to the current folder, which is the folder from which you're starting the program. Just as with any other executable or command. When you type `less readme.txt`, it opens the readme.txt file in the current directory. Same with Java.

Comment: ok, that pretty much resolves my concern then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you provide a relative path to the constructor of the class `File` like `new File("config.properties")`, behind the scene, the absolute path built is

```
System.getProperty("user.dir") / config.properties
```

with `user.dir` that is actually the `User working directory` which is also the directory from which you launch your command.